# Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, yt-dlp, disnake

I am creating disnake music bot. The error is:

```
[in#0 @ 00000233f8d71500] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duDUqBtxwXk.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is part of my code:

```py
import disnake
import asyncio
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
import ffmpeg


YTDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'False', 'simulate':'True', 'key':"FFmpegExtractAudio"}
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}


async def play_music(inter):
        global YDTL_OPTIONS, FFMPEG_OPTIONS
    print(tm.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"play_music begin")
    id = int(inter.guild.id)
    with YoutubeDL(YTDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

    song = {
            'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + url,
            'thumbnail': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + url + '/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLD5uL4xKN-IUfez6KIW_j5y70mlig',
            'source': info['formats'][0]['url'],
            'title': info['title']
        }   self.vc[id].play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=r"C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe",source=song["source"], **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
    print(tm.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),"play_music end")
```

I tried to write `source = song['source']` instead of `source = song['link']`, but it didn't seem helpful.

Comment: I have found an answer, you can do not answer to my question. (or just close this question)